# How to create documentation for a c++ project?

Tags: c++

I am using the Ubuntu OS to create a library written in c++.
I've created an shared library and now I need to document my work.
I would like to know what is the smartest and fastest way to do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're looking for API documentation of your classes / types, you might want to look into [Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/).

Comment: I've installed on Ubuntu doxygen-gui. How to work with it?THX

Comment: Try [first steps](http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/starting.html) from the [manual](http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/manual.html). If you have specific questions/problems, you should consider asking a new question on SO.