# Make own function description like in API methods

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Is there some alternative way to document your own functions/methods/variables in objective-c?
Like XML documentation in C# and java doc in Java.

Comment: Not mentioned in the answers (or linked question): [AppleDoc](http://gentlebytes.com/appledoc/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm having a [deja vu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6982078/how-to-create-documentation-for-a-c-project/6982109#6982109) ;-) Anyway, it looks like [Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.org) can [handle Objective-C as well](http://www.duckrowing.com/2010/03/18/documenting-objective-c-with-doxygen-part-i/); I have not personally tried it though.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you to use [Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.org). It is what we use internally at work and it works really well. The fact that you could then also use the same system for other languages is also an added bonus if you eventually come to need that.

There is a good guide for automating the generation of your Doxygen docs with your builds here: http://www.guidebee.biz/forum/viewthread.php?tid=168

Answer (score 2):

There has been some development since the other answers have been posted.

[AppleDoc](http://gentlebytes.com/appledoc/) has evolved and become quite nice. It creates doc pages in the style of Apple's own pages, which is what you are after if I interpret your question correctly.

Documentation of the comments format [here](http://gentlebytes.com/appledoc-docs-comments/).

Answer (score 0):

Good news everyone! Xcode 5 now has built-in support for DOxygen style comments. So, you can comment your methods like this:

```
/*!
 * Provides an NSManagedObjectContext singleton appropriate for use on the main 
 * thread. If the context doesn't already exist it is created and bound to the 
 * persistent store coordinator for the application, otherwise the existing 
 * singleton contextis returned.
 * \param someParameter You can even add parameters
 * \returns The a shared NSManagedObjectContext for the application.
 */
+ (NSManagedObjectContext *)sharedContext;
```

### Inline help will look like this:

[image: inline help]

### Quick help will look like this:

[image: quick help]

### And sidebar help will look like this:

[image: sidebar help]

Here's a handy code snippet you can add the your Xcode Code Snippet library to make method documentation simple:

```
/**
 <#description#>
 @param <#parameter#>
 @returns <#retval#>
 @exception <#throws#>
 */
```

[image: doxygen code snippet]

Now, you can just type "doxy" and poof! You have your doxygen template.